# Monitoring usage metrics on a desktop C# application

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, azure-application-insights

I need to start tracking the usage of a non-web, desktop application (.NET, WPF).

Mostly things such as buttons clicked, features used, potentially also performance metrics.
I'm basically hesitating between 3 options, first 2 being primarily targeted for web applications:

- **Azure Application Insights**
- **Google Analytics** (Using a binding for .NET such as GData)
- **Some homemade solution**
  I'm not a fan of this solution, but it does offer the advantage of being somewhat more easily customized to our needs. But it also mean we would need to develop everything to track, write to disk, send to a web server and display in a user-friendly way the usage data. Still wondering how this could be a cost effective solution.

I'd like to know, is one of these options significantly better than the others for my situation? (To track what buttons are clicked by users)

Is there another solution I'm not aware of that could potentially be used in this case?

I'm also curious to know your opinions and your experiences with these technologies.

Sources:

- https://www.anupams.net/azure-application-insights-google-analytics-sharepoint/
- https://dev.to/expecho/monitoring-non-website-applications-using-azure-application-insights-part-1--42oa
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-gdata/

Comment: Has the app got a remote database? If so you could log to that.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to vote for closing this question as you can't ask for recommendations of the library on this site, it is prohibited by the rules.

Comment: You can't monitor a desktop application with web analytics, Azure, Google, or otherwise. It's completely different. A desktop application might not even have a network connection. You will probably have to modify the application itself.

Comment: (a member of Application Insights team) We have many on-premise customers who report usage telemetry for desktop applications. You can use customEvents, customMetrics document types.